# How do I get my computer to shut down with the power button?

Tags: shutdown

When I press the power button on my PC, it brings up an interface with four options: Lock, suspend, restart, shut down. Is there any way to have it simply shut down when I press the power button?

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Try installing `gnome-tweak-tool` and see if the options there can help you. To install it, open your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard and type the following command in the terminal window: sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

Answer (score 14):

Install **dconf-editor** first

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

At Dconf editor window, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search for "button-power". Otherwise, navigate to

org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power

[image: dconf-editor. Image 1]

Change the value to from interactive to shutdown just like this

[image: dconf-editor. Image 2]

That's it

PS: Please mark as accepted if working